# Joining Different Tables with one table coumn name and another table's coumn values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new for oracle. here i have created two table as follows:
Table 1:

```
create table emp_Det(emp_id varchar2(30), emp_name varchar2(80), PLSQL varchar2(20), ADF varchar2(20));
```

Table 2:

```
create table group(grp_id varchar2(30), grp_name varchar2(80));
```

I have inserted values in both tables as follows:

Table1:emp_Det

```
Emp_id    Emp_name   PLSQL    ADF
Sample1    Sample1     5       5
Sample3    Sample2     5       5
Sample3    Sample3     5       5
```

Table2:group

```
grp_id      grp_name
ORA          PLSQL
ORAS         ADF
```

We have to select columns from these two tables and have to join  one table's column name with another table's column value. the columns names are emp_id,Emp_name,Grp_id,Grp_name,rating.

for example, In first table(**EMP_DET**) **"PLSQL"** is column name and "**PLSQL**" is a value of Second table(**Group**) column grp_name and result should come as follows

```
EMP_ID   EMP_NAME    GRP_ID     GRP_NAME    Rating
Sample1   Sample1     ORA        PLSQL         5
Sample1   Sample1     ORAS       ADF           5
```

please help me out to prepare query or procedure or suggest me

Comment: BTW, naming a table with a reserved word ("group") isn't such a good idea IMHO...

Comment: will be followed from next time, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 11g and above then you can try this:

```
select t.*, g.grp_id
from
(select *
from emp_det
unpivot
(
  rating for group_name in ("PLSQL", "ADF")
)) t join "group" g on t.group_name = g.grp_name
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9900a/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (not completly sure about the syntax):

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_name, grp_id, grp_name, plsql AS rating
  FROM emp_det, group
 WHERE grp_name = 'PLSQL'
UNION
SELECT emp_id, emp_name, grp_id, grp_name, adf AS rating
  FROM emp_det, group
 WHERE grp_name = 'ADF';
```